# Line-break at any given character in sentence HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I got a `<p>` element containing several `<span>` elements, and I am trying to add linebreaks at wherever the container wraps. However, it currently breaks on the spans.

Visual example:

`Lorem Ipsum Dolor   |
Sit amet            |
conseceteuerblabla  |`

What I try to achieve:

`Lorem Ipsum Dolor Si|
t amet conseceteuerb|
labla               |`

**How can you achieve this preferably using the same markup?**

---

My code:

```css
p {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: calc(2em + 3vw);
  
  word-break: break-word;
}

span {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>Ipsum</span>
  <span>Dolor</span>
  <span>Sit</span>
  <span>azerty</span>
  <span>qwerty</span>
  <span>asdfghjk</span>
  <span>qwertyuiopasdfghjkl</span>
</p>
```

Comment: `word-break: break-all`

Comment: It's isn't breaking on spans, it is breaking on spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`break-word` is not a valid value for `word-break`. You must use `break-all`

```css
    p {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: calc(2em + 3vw);
      
      word-break: break-all;
    }

    span {
      word-break: break-all;
    }
```

```html
    <p>
      <span>Loremloremlorem</span>
      <span>Ipsumipsumipsumipsm</span>
      <span>Dolordolordolordolordolordolor</span>
      <span>Sitsitsitsitsitsitsit</span>
      <span>asdasdasdsadasdasdasdasdasd</span>
      <span>qweqweqweqw</span>
      <span>zxc</span>
      <span>tyutyutyutyutyutyutyutyu</span>
    </p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`P{
 word-break: break-all;
}`

instead of  word-break: break-word;